# No url given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable and no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock'

Tags: docker

I am trying to run spring boot application as a docker container and I am trying the mvn docker build on windows system, it is giving some error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.13.9:build (default-cli) on project restaurant-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.13.9:build failed: No url given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable and no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock' -> [Help 1]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Just an error message on its own isn't usually enough to diagnose a problem; can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  It looks like you've rendered a more complete error output into a PNG file, replacing that with the plain-text error and including any source code necessary to demonstrate the problem will be helpful.  (Just looking at the text error message you quote: is Docker actually running?  Why do you need it as part of your build?)

Comment: please find the text for of error log

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.13.9:build (default-cli) on project restaurant-service: Execution default-cli of goal org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.13.9:build failed: No url given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable and no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock' -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 2):

The error shows that you are not running docker locally on your machine.

In case you have docker up and running and you can execute docker commands with cmd. Please check if you have exposed deamon on localhost , Go to

`docker desktop --> setting --> Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS`

Comment: i have set the option

Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS
Exposing daemon on TCP without TLS helps legacy clients connect to the daemon. It also makes yourself vulnerable to remote code execution attacks. Use with caution. in Docker Desktop settings, and i can run docker commands also. but when trying to do mvn docker:build is gives above error